# Unread Result Found in MySQL Connector

Tags: python, mysql-connector

This is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import pandas as pd
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import time
```

Here we are going to create a function that will allow us to connect to the mySQL server

```
def create_server_connection(host_name, user_name, user_password):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=user_password
        )
        print("MySQL Database connection succesful!")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
    return connection

connection = create_server_connection("localhost", "root", "password")
```

Here we are going to actually create the database

```
def create_database(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        print("Database created successfully")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")

create_database_query = "CREATE DATABASE twitter"
create_database(connection, create_database_query)

def create_db_connection(host_name, user_name, user_password, db_name):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=user_password,
            database=db_name
        )
        print("MySQL Database connection succesful!")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
    return connection
```

Make a function to take and store the SQL queries and pass them to the `cursor.execute()` method so that can they can executed on the SQL server.

```
def execute_query(connection, query, data=None):
    cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    try:
        cursor.execute(query, data)

        if "SELECT" in query.upper():
            # Fetch and return results only if it's a SELECT query
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            return result
        else:
            connection.commit()  # Commit for non-SELECT queries
            return None  # Return None for non-SELECT queries

    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
        return None  # Return None in case of an error
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
```

Now we are going to start creating the two tables that we need for the database

```
drop_tweet_table_query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tweet;"
execute_query(connection, drop_tweet_table_query)

create_tweet_table = """
CREATE TABLE tweet (
    tweet_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT,
    tweet_ts DATETIME,
    tweet_text VARCHAR(140)
);
"""

connection = create_db_connection("localhost", "root", "password", "twitter")
execute_query(connection, create_tweet_table)

drop_follow_table_query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS follow;"
execute_query(connection, drop_follow_table_query)

create_follows_table = """
CREATE TABLE follows (
    user_id INT,
    follows_id INT
    );
"""

connection = create_db_connection("localhost", "root", "password", "twitter")
execute_query(connection, create_follows_table)
```

Now we are going to populate the follows tables with the data from the csv file

```
def insert_follows_data(connection, csv_file_path):
    follows_insert_query = "INSERT INTO follows (user_id, follows_id) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    
    try:
        with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(csv_reader)
            
            for row in csv_reader:
                user_id, follows_id = map(int, row)
                data = (user_id, follows_id)
                execute_query(connection, follows_insert_query % data)
        
        print("Data inserted into follows table successfully!")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")

csv_file_path = 'hw1_data/follows.csv'
insert_follows_data(connection, csv_file_path)
```

Now we are moving onto performance testing for posting tweets

```
def insert_tweet_data(connection, csv_file_path):
    tweet_insert_query = "INSERT INTO tweet (user_id, tweet_ts, tweet_text) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"

    try:
        with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            next(csv_reader)

            start_time = datetime.now()

            for row in csv_reader:
                user_id, tweet_text = row[0], row[1]
                tweet_ts = datetime.now()
                data = (user_id, tweet_ts, tweet_text)
                execute_query(connection, tweet_insert_query, data)

            end_time = datetime.now()
            elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
            print(f'Time taken to load tweets: {elapsed_time.total_seconds()} seconds')

        print("Data inserted into tweet table successfully!")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")

def execute_query(connection, query, data=None):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
        connection.commit()
        print("Query Successful!")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
        

csv_file_path_tweets = 'hw1_data/tweet.csv'
insert_tweet_data(connection, csv_file_path_tweets)
```

and also performance testing for home timelines

```
import random 

def get_home_timeline(connection, user_id):
    home_timeline_query = """
        SELECT t.*
        FROM tweet t
        WHERE t.user_id IN (
            SELECT follows_id
            FROM follows
            WHERE user_id = %s
        )
        ORDER BY t.tweet_ts DESC
        LIMIT 10;
    """
    data = (user_id,)

    cursor = None
    results = None

    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
        start_time = datetime.now()
        cursor.execute(home_timeline_query, data)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        end_time = datetime.now()
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f'Time taken to retrieve home timeline: {elapsed_time.total_seconds()} seconds')
        print("Result:", results)
        print("----------------------")

    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()

    return results


def simulate_home_timeline_retrieval(connection, num_simulations):
    all_user_ids_query = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM tweet;"

    try:
        with connection.cursor(dictionary=True) as cursor:
            cursor.execute(all_user_ids_query)
            all_user_ids = [user['user_id'] for user in cursor.fetchall()]

        for _ in range(num_simulations):
            random_user_id = random.choice(all_user_ids)
            print(f"Simulating home timeline retrieval for user {random_user_id}")

            with connection.cursor(dictionary=True) as cursor:
                try:
                    # Use cursor.execute directly for SELECT queries
                    get_home_timeline_query = """
                        SELECT t.*
                        FROM tweet t
                        WHERE t.user_id IN (
                            SELECT follows_id
                            FROM follows
                            WHERE user_id = %s
                        )
                        ORDER BY t.tweet_ts DESC
                        LIMIT 10;
                    """
                    data = (random_user_id,)
                    start_time = datetime.now()
                    cursor.execute(get_home_timeline_query, data)
                    results = cursor.fetchall()  # Fetch results for SELECT query
                    end_time = datetime.now()
                    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
                    print(f'Time taken to retrieve home timeline: {elapsed_time.total_seconds()} seconds')
                    print("Result:", results)
                    print("----------------------")

                except Error as err:
                    print(f"Error: '{err}'")

    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")


#Let's count to make sure we have 1 million tweets

def count_tweets(connection):
    count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tweet;"
    
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    tweet_count = None

    try:
        cursor.execute(count_query)
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        if result is not None and len(result) > 0:
            tweet_count = result[0]
            print(f"Total number of tweets: {tweet_count}")
        else:
            print("Unable to fetch tweet count.")

    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")
    finally:
        cursor.close()

    return tweet_count

count_tweets(connection)

and now we can run the home timeline performance code

num_simulations = 100
simulate_home_timeline_retrieval(connection, num_simulations)
```

but when I run the simulate_home_timeline_retrieval or the tweet_count methods it gives me 'Error: 'Unread result found'' and i can't figure out how to fix it!

I've tried fixing the execute query and home_timeline functions but nothing has worked

Comment: Too much code. Can you please reduce it to the relevant parts of it?

Comment: The test `if 'SELECT' in query.upper():` is not a good way to distinguish SELECT from other queries. What it if's `INSERT INTO tablename SELECT columns... FROM othertable`. Maybe you should use `if query.upper().startswith("SELECT"):`